# I unable delete campaign collection in monngoose , expressjs

Tags: express, mongoose

**My error:**  i am getting this error while i try to delete my collection in mongodb using mongoose

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_Id' of undefined
    at exports.postDeleteCampaign (C:\Users\RudraSimha\desktop\hackthon\controllers\admin.js:132:42)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\RudraSimha\desktop\hackthon\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

const campaign = new Campaign({

```
  Campname:req.body.campname,
  Title:req.body.title,
  Email:req.body.email,
  Start:req.body.start,
  End:req.body.end,
  Time:req.body.time,
  FacebookURL:req.body.facebooklink,
  TwitterURL:req.body.twitterlink,
  InstagramURL:req.body.instagramlink,
  LinkedinURL:req.body.linkedinlink,
  Description:req.body.editordata ,
  Primarycolor:req.body.primarycolor, 
  Secondarycolor:req.body.secondarycolor, 
  userId:req.user._id ,
  Logo:`${logo}`,
  Banner:`uploads/${filename}`
});
 campaign.save().then(post => {

  console.log(campaign);
  req.flash('success', { msg: 'Campaign Created successfully' });
     res.redirect('/create-photo-campaign');

 });
```

}

**My route :**  This my post route for deleting

```
exports.postDeleteCampaign = (req, res, next) => {

 Campaign.findByIdAndDelete(req.campaign._Id , (err) => {

    if (err) { return next(err); }
    req.flash('info', { msg: 'Campaign has been deleted.' });
    res.redirect('/campaign-list');
  });
};
```

I want delete my my campaign collection but , i tried using different ways but no use

Comment: That is not the issue

Comment: still it is showing  Cannot read property '_Id' of undefined

Comment: Maybe what you want is the req.body.campaign. Can you post your html?

Comment: @Danizavtz i just want to delete the campaign collection which is already stored in mongo db using mongoose

Comment: Where you defined the req.campaign?

Comment: Added above , please check it  @Danizavtz

Comment: `req.campaign` is undefined, are you sure you don't want to access `req.body._Id`?

Comment: I'm talking about the campaign in your middleware `postDeleteCampaign`, you are acessing a key `req.campaign`, where you defined that value?

Comment: campaign is my data base model

Comment: i am not using any middle ware

Answer (score 0):

if you want delete collection use

```
mongoose.connection.db.dropCollection('campaign', function(err, result) {
    // ...
});
```

findOneAndDelete() used to delete documents

try not to pass req and res as parameters, you are putting express to the bottom of your application. Pass the data that you use to consult, for example an id string.